# best way to add third party js and css

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery, css

I need to add a third party js and CSS to my template head.

I'm getting Leverage browser caching and someone advised me to load the files locally.

created a directory in root: assets/third-party/
and setup a cron job that get the files from their site and store them in that directory.

What is the best way to add them to the head in Joomla 3.x? I've tried these ones

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>assets/third-party/float.js">
```

```
<?php JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'assets/third-party/float.js');?>

<link href="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>assets/third-party/float.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using JCH Optimize Pro for optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd much rather deliver CSS and JS files via a CDN than using something like JCH optimise to combine them all into 1 file. With `HTTP/2`, files are delivered much quicker, so a couple more http requests won't make any difference.

If there is a CDN version, then simply use:

```
JHtml::_('script', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FOO/BAR/file.js');

JHtml::_('stylesheet', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FOO/BAR/file.css');
```

else:

```
JHtml::_('script', JUri::base() . 'assets/third-party/float.js');

JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::base() . 'assets/third-party/float.css');
```

Comment: Thanks, and is the CSS one correct: JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::base() . 'assets/third-party/float.css');

Comment: The errors I get are mainly for those 2 files and also I use comodo for SSL and have their trust logo on the footer and Google gives Leverage browser caching error for these URLs: https://secure.comodo.com/trustlogo/images/popup/seal_bg.gif (6 hours)
https://secure.comodo.com/…rustlogo/images/popup/warranty_level.gif (6 hours) and ask to Compressing https://secure.comodo.com/trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js could save 12.3KiB (70% reduction).

I tried to do the same with trust logo script and load it locally but it doesn't work, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: here is what they asked me to ad to the head: <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Go with `JHtml::script` and `JHtml::stylesheet` - it is by the cleanest way of including CSS and JS in Joomla.

Comment: is this the correct syntax? also how can I add the defer and async attributes?
<?php JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'assets/third-party/float.js');?>